# sql oracle - LIKE with LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, in the table A i have the column `numbS` that can be duplicated, each `numbS` has a `startYear` and `endYear`, i want to get the column `code` from the table B where the columns `startYear` and `endYear` is the same as column `year`, and the `numSFK` equals `numS`

**TableB**

```
idS numS   year        code
10    1    2017/2018   123
20    2    2016/2017   456    
30    1    2016/2017   789     
40    2    2017/2018   159
```

**TableA**

```
idP  startYear endYear  numSFK
x     2017       2018    2  
w     2016       2017    1    
z     2017       2018    1
```

**Result**

```
numS   code 
2       159  
1       789    
1       123
```

I tried with the below query but always i get the column code empty

```
select
    mp.numSFK,        
    sm.code
from tableA mp
         LEFT JOIN TableB sm ON sm.numS = mp.numSFK AND
         mp.startYear LIKE '%' || sm.year || '%' AND mp.endYear LIKE '%' || sm.year  || '%'
```

Comment: @cwa i get an error `ORA-01722: invalid number` when i replace `||` by `+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should concatenate the `tableA` `startYear` and `endYear` values together to compare against the `tableB` `year` column:

```sql
SELECT A.numSFK AS numS,
       B.code
FROM TableA A
LEFT JOIN TableB B ON B.numS = A.numSFK
                  AND B.year = A.startYear || '/' || A.endYear
ORDER BY numS DESC, code DESC
```

Output:

```
NUMS    CODE
2       159
1       789
1       123
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=af971137459a6dfbf333208f4bd3ecb8)

Answer (score 0):

You did mistake in column placement

Replace

```
mp.startYear LIKE '%' || sm.year || '%' AND mp.endYear LIKE '%' || sm.year  || '%'
```

With

```
sm.year LIKE '%' || mp.startYear || '%' AND sm.year LIKE '%' || mp.endYear  || '%'
```